# Write file inside zip or compress file

Tags: php, zip, compression

I don´t find nothing about this and by this i put my question here

For example if i have one file with this content inside zip file or other kind of compress file :

```
<?php
$name="Jhon";
$phone="123456789";
$city="London";
?>
```

I want for example access this file and writte from form for change some inforations and also can read and all from zip file or compress file , tar , etc , etc

Also i want include this file inside of this zip in one file for get informations

It´s possible do this with php or for other side it´s impossible ?

Thank´s , the best regards

Comment: you don't work "inside the zip". you decompress the file from the zip, make your modifications, then re-add it to the zip, replacing the original version.

Comment: Yes it´s possible , but the most important it´s possible include file inside zip in one php file ?

Comment: Yes, you can deal with zips in php: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the file, change it, and then re-add it back to the archive (assuming that you have the ZipArchive class installed).

```
$zip = New \ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('yourarchive.zip');
if (true === $res) 
{
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/', 'test.php');

    $contents = file('*your filename*');
    foreach ($contents as $line) 
    {
        //perform alterations;
    }

    unset ($contents[2]); //remove line 2;
    $contents[] = "aaaa"; //append "aaaa" to the end of the file

    file_put_contents('test.php', $contents);

    // do your edits to the file
    $zip->addFile('test.php');
    $zip->close();
}
```